# Why MSVC compiler ignore my code and call stdclib function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I use **Visual Studio 2022 with v143** platform toolset

Have that code (dll):

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned char* buff;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    int len = 1000;
    while (len--)
        *buff++ = 0;
}
```

**MSVC project settings**:
**Compiler**:
Disable Security Check (/GS-)

**Linker**:
/NODEFAULTLIB
/ENTRY:"DllMain"

But compiler replace my code to do call memset() in stdclib
Listing dllmain.asm

```masm
_DllMain@12 PROC                    ; COMDAT

; 7    : {

    push    esi

; 8    :     int len = 1000;

    mov esi, DWORD PTR ?buff@@3PAEA     ; buff
    push    1000                    ; 000003e8H
    push    0
    push    esi
    call    _memset
    add esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
    add esi, 1000               ; 000003e8H
    mov DWORD PTR ?buff@@3PAEA, esi     ; buff

; 9    :     while (len--)
; 10   :         *buff++ = 0;
; 11   : }

    xor eax, eax
    pop esi
    ret 12                  ; 0000000cH
_DllMain@12 ENDP
```

When I try compile exe file is fine, but can't compile dll because linker ends with error "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset".

Why compiler do it? How to disable it?

**Update**:
I found solution
by adding volatile local var
`volatile unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buff;`

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned char* buff;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    int len = 1000;
    volatile unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buff;
    while (len--)
        *p++ = 0;
}
```

```masm
_DllMain@12 PROC

; 19   :     int len = 1000;
; 20   :     volatile unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buff;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR ?buff@@3PAEA     ; buff
    mov eax, 1000               ; 000003e8H
$LL2@DllMain:

; 21   :     while (len--)
; 22   :         *p++ = 0;

    mov BYTE PTR [ecx], 0
    inc ecx
    sub eax, 1
    jne SHORT $LL2@DllMain

; 23   : }

    ret 12                  ; 0000000cH
_DllMain@12 ENDP
```

Comment: "_Why compiler do it?_": It is a valid optimization. In every C++ implementation `memset` must be a function defined to behave in the way that corresponds to your function's behavior. If you use a flag like `/NODEFAULTLIB`  then you generally need to provide the standard library function implementation yourself. (But there is probably some flag to tell MSVC to not do this optimization.)

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, but really I not wanna do 'call' I need to be code of memset will be included in DllMain, so I need __forceinline to my memset, but it doesnt work too, and compiler just do call my memset function.

Comment: @user774076 The [answer](/a/48679675) to [How to prevent auto optimization from for loop to memset() in Visual Studio?](/q/48676760) says "The only relevant compiler option I see in [the list of compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=msvc-170), besides disabling optimization, is /kernel, which produces a binary that can run in the Windows kernel." Also, the MSDN's ...

Comment: @user774076 (cont.) [MSVC++ 2005 automatically calling memset?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a51fe950-cd74-4133-8d84-1bc07b353bc2/msvc-2005-automatically-calling-memset?forum=Vsexpressvc) has, although this is for a considerably earlier version, in answer by Wayne on "Thursday, February 7, 2008 4:41 AM" that "Disabling works in VC++ 2008 Express Edition - it eliminates the call to memset. If you have it set for minimal code, then it's not disabled. Does 2005 have an option "Optimization: Disabled (/Od)"? If so, use it. Also, ...

Comment: @user774076 (cont.) "Favor Size or Speed" should be set to "Neither", and "Whole Program Optimization" to "No"." For some reason, my copy of VS 2017 doesn't have any option for DLL's, so I can't directly test whether or not this works properly there. Nonetheless, you may wish to try it yourself to check if it solves your problem.

Comment: in what problem link with *ntdllp.lib* and use `memset* from *ntdll.dll* ?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Fully disable optimizations is not my way. Its bad.

Comment: @user774076 If you want the compiler to produce some particular machine instructions (e.g. a loop without any function call), then use inline assembly. Otherwise you generally can't have such strong guarantees. The compiler decided that the loop is large enough so that a call to an optimized memset function is worth it and it is the compiler's job to produce as optimized code as possible. Why is a function call not acceptable in you case?

Comment: Can you please post your edit as an answer? Solutions don't belong in questions.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qa68dYqTP can't reproduce; I wonder why.

Comment: @JanSchultke Some compile flags like /GL can affect this.
There is better example https://godbolt.org/z/d71q4boq9

Comment: @user17732522 "If you want the compiler to produce some particular machine instructions (e.g. a loop without any function call), then use inline assembly" - Just be aware that that's not supported for x64 code; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=msvc-170

Comment: This seems like a XY problem.  Do you actually want to disable the optimization or do you want to resolve the missing symbol at link time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution
by adding volatile local var
`volatile unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buff;`

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned char* buff;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    int len = 1000;
    volatile unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buff;
    while (len--)
        *p++ = 0;
}
```

```masm
_DllMain@12 PROC

; 19   :     int len = 1000;
; 20   :     volatile unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buff;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR ?buff@@3PAEA     ; buff
    mov eax, 1000               ; 000003e8H
$LL2@DllMain:

; 21   :     while (len--)
; 22   :         *p++ = 0;

    mov BYTE PTR [ecx], 0
    inc ecx
    sub eax, 1
    jne SHORT $LL2@DllMain

; 23   : }

    ret 12                  ; 0000000cH
_DllMain@12 ENDP
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing C++ compilers will often recognize loops that do the equivalent of `memset` and `memcpy` and replace the code with an appropriate call.  In some cases, they might even inline the code.  This is a good thing for performance, as the implementations that come with the compiler (or the standard library it uses) are highly optimized.

It's not clear whether you actually want to disable the optimization or whether you're assuming that's what you have to do to resolve the linker error.

In C++, you commonly compile for a "hosted" environment, which means that standard library is available.  Some compilers also support a "freestanding" mode, which means the program cannot use the standard library (and there may be other limitations as well).  Freestanding is commonly used for embedded systems.

Even in freestanding mode, C++ compilers may generate calls to memcpy and memset.  Even with optimizations disabled.  So finding a way to disable the optimization in this example might not solve the entire problem.

The reason the call to memset is not resolved in this example is that the `/NODEFAULTLIB` option told the linker not to consider functions from libraries it normally would have checked.

Option 1:  Remove `/NODEFAULTLIB`.  The linker will resolve the call against the standard library.  On Windows, there exist both static and DLL versions of the standard library.  You can select which you want, but, if you're making a DLL, you usually want the DLL version of the standard library.

Option 2:  If `/NODEFAULTLIB` is required to prevent libraries other than the standard library from being considered, then you can still tell the linker to consider the standard library.

Option 3:  If your DLL must not use any version of the standard library, provide your own definition of `memset` (and `memcpy` if necessary).  You can write the obvious implementations, or you make wrappers around WinAPI calls like ZeroMemory and CopyMemory.